# Dynamic skeleton using Kinect

Tags: kinect, openni, kinect-sdk, simple-openni

I'm asking if there is any ideas how to expand the skeleton extracted by OpenNI or Microsoft SDK from the Kinect device to add more joints to it? For example, if a man is holding a stick then the skeleton will add one extra joint representing the stick? If you could please let me know if there is any solution to solve this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No...ish.

You can not add or delete joints that are reported from the SDK.  Those that are tracked by default are the only ones you have immediate access to throw the SDK.

It is possibly to analyze the skeleton and/or depth data to determine where additional joints are, with libraries such as OpenCV, but it is a much more complicated process.  You would end up with another skeleton data structure with your unique data in it, however you decided to store it.

I'm not familiar with any examples that demonstrate the process.  The source code to one of the open source Kinect drivers may be a good source.

Comment: Thanks! I was pretty sure that it is not possible with windows SDK. In OpenNI you can access the depth points of the tracked players, so what I thought about it adding one more limb to the skeleton Is it possible with OpenNI? I just need a clue or a guide of the steps needed to accomplish what I want, so if you could please assist or guide me. Many Thanks

Comment: You can access the depth data in the official SDK too.  It is not a lack of data that is the problem, it is knowing how to process that data.  Both SDKs do a lot of stuff with the depth data and other data to create the skeleton and do not provide an "add joint" function because niether would now how to process the data to. Generate that point.  You will need to do all that work yourself with whatever data gives you what you need.  You can try the source to 'OpenNI' or 'freenect' for clues on how to produce skeleton points.

Comment: and is the source code of creating the normal skeleton accessible?

Comment: In one of the open source libraries, that would be your best bet.  I believe OpenNI does not do skeletons, leaving that to NITE (which is closed source).  But it is worth a scan of the code.